# Jsf datatable optimization count query

Tags: oracle, hibernate, jsf, jpa

I have a JSF datatable and displaing an entity that contains images which are lazy loaded. Loaded after clicking on the row to see details.

But I have to display the imagecount in the datatable. The datatable uses pagination and displays 15 rows per page.

I use following annotations for the mapping

```
    // Fetch type must be lazy due to out of memory error in eager mode
@OneToMany(cascade = { CascadeType.REMOVE, CascadeType.MERGE }, mappedBy = "alarm", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, orphanRemoval = true)
@OrderBy("unixtime ASC")
@LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.EXTRA) // allows .size() and .contains() without initializing the whole collection
private volatile Set<AlarmImage> alarmImages = new HashSet<AlarmImage>();
```

With this method to get the number of images

```
 /**
 * @return the number of alarm images in this alarm
 */
public Integer getCountAlarmImages() {
    // wont initalize whole collection because LazyCollectionOption.EXTRA
    return this.alarmImages.size();
}
```

This is the hibernate log

```
[2016-10-07 08:51:13,095] [WebContainer : 1] DEBUG org.hibernate.SQL [] logStatement - select count(ID) from ALARM_IMAGE where ALARM_FK =?
[2016-10-07 08:51:13,190] [WebContainer : 1] DEBUG org.hibernate.SQL [] logStatement - select count(ID) from ALARM_IMAGE where ALARM_FK =?
[2016-10-07 08:51:13,282] [WebContainer : 1] DEBUG org.hibernate.SQL [] logStatement - select count(ID) from ALARM_IMAGE where ALARM_FK =?
[2016-10-07 08:51:13,375] [WebContainer : 1] DEBUG org.hibernate.SQL [] logStatement - select count(ID) from ALARM_IMAGE where ALARM_FK =?
[2016-10-07 08:51:13,466] [WebContainer : 1] DEBUG org.hibernate.SQL [] logStatement - select count(ID) from ALARM_IMAGE where ALARM_FK =?
[2016-10-07 08:51:13,559] [WebContainer : 1] DEBUG org.hibernate.SQL [] logStatement - select count(ID) from ALARM_IMAGE where ALARM_FK =?
[2016-10-07 08:51:13,651] [WebContainer : 1] DEBUG org.hibernate.SQL [] logStatement - select count(ID) from ALARM_IMAGE where ALARM_FK =?
[2016-10-07 08:51:13,744] [WebContainer : 1] DEBUG org.hibernate.SQL [] logStatement - select count(ID) from ALARM_IMAGE where ALARM_FK =?
[2016-10-07 08:51:13,836] [WebContainer : 1] DEBUG org.hibernate.SQL [] logStatement - select count(ID) from ALARM_IMAGE where ALARM_FK =?
[2016-10-07 08:51:13,930] [WebContainer : 1] DEBUG org.hibernate.SQL [] logStatement - select count(ID) from ALARM_IMAGE where ALARM_FK =?
[2016-10-07 08:51:14,022] [WebContainer : 1] DEBUG org.hibernate.SQL [] logStatement - select count(ID) from ALARM_IMAGE where ALARM_FK =?
[2016-10-07 08:51:14,117] [WebContainer : 1] DEBUG org.hibernate.SQL [] logStatement - select count(ID) from ALARM_IMAGE where ALARM_FK =?
[2016-10-07 08:51:14,210] [WebContainer : 1] DEBUG org.hibernate.SQL [] logStatement - select count(ID) from ALARM_IMAGE where ALARM_FK =?
[2016-10-07 08:51:14,302] [WebContainer : 1] DEBUG org.hibernate.SQL [] logStatement - select count(ID) from ALARM_IMAGE where ALARM_FK =?
[2016-10-07 08:51:14,395] [WebContainer : 1] DEBUG org.hibernate.SQL [] logStatement - select count(ID) from ALARM_IMAGE where ALARM_FK =?
```

My problem is that the pagination needs an average of 1.5 seconds to load is it possible to optimize this? Maybe paralell loading the number of images per alarm? Is this possible in the jsf datatable?

Edit:

Hibernate version: 4.2.17.Final

The row definition in the xhtml file

```
<p:column>
    <h:outputText value="#{alarm.countAlarmImages}" />
</p:column>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't think there's a possibility to "parallel load" these, it's possible that it's already doing that anyway, but I do have some ideas for you:

1.
keep a field with `@Formula`, that you'll run when all of the alarms are fetched ( The @Formula will be part of a query you're already doing instead of a new one )

```
@Formula("(select count(1) from ALARM_IMAGE AI where AI.ALARM_FK = _this.ALARM_PK)") 
private Int alarmImageCount;
```

can't quite remember what's the current entity is referenced as in the `@Formula`, check out the sql generated by hibernate and you'll figure it out, but I think it's usually `_this`

2.
Looks like you're using primefaces, you can do something like show the new page, but keep the image counts missing (or put some indication that they are loading) until they are fully loaded, and then ajax them in when they're initialized. It definitely can be done but will take some time. Look into the `p:remoteCommand` component and `RequestContext` object if you're going down this path.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I appriciate it. Because the loadingtime was not a requirement specifically defined in my task i left it as it is now. I will accept your answer because a asynchron request would be the way to go